# android private attribute suddenly become null

Tags: android, memory, jvm

Android TV app in strict mode initialise my AAR library like this:

```
public class MainApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    LibraryApplication.init(this);
}}
```

The library

```
public class LibraryApplication extends Application {

@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
private static LibraryApplication instance;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static void init(Application application) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new LibraryApplication(application);
        return;
    }

    throw new RuntimeException("Library already initialized.");
}

private final LibraryActivityHandler activityHandler;

public LibraryApplication(final Application application) {
    this.activityHandler = new LibraryActivityHandler(this);
}}
```

LibraryActivityHandler

```
class LibraryActivityHandler implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

private Activity currentActivity;

@Override
public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
    assert activity != null;
    this.currentActivity = activity;
    //Just to show you that activity is really not null
    currentActivity.getLayoutInflater();
    Log.debug("activity set");
}

boolean isActivityNull() {
    Log.debug("is null: " + (currentActivity == null));
    return currentActivity == null;
}
```

Question: In the log I can see "activity set" and later I can see "is null: true". Can someone please explain to me how current Activity might become null ?

After over 10 years with Android and Java,

I am admitting that I don't have much ideas about it.

edit: The app is also using Dagger library, and the strict mode is not causing the issue.

Comment: Instead of making `LibraryApplication` static try extending `LibraryApplication`. And implement `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` inside library application.

Comment: Quoting 'later I can see "is null: true"', Later, how much later? In what scenario? Another thing confusing is LibararyApplication extends Application and You are instantiating another application within your MainApplication? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by multi processes application.